# Is LaTeX a notable skill (for example in your CV?)

Tags: scientific-workplace

I‘m a student in engineering and in the last few years I really fell in love with LaTeX. I‘d even go as far as to say that it‘s some kind of a hobby to read about new packages or possibilities here on TEX.SX and so on...

The last few days I was searching for internships and as I was preparing my CV and resume I was not sure weather or not my ability to use LaTeX (maybe a bit more than just with „default settings“) is worth mentioning or not.

In most companies you just use MS Office (at least if you are not in a researching department)
So I think it won‘t give me any bonuses, and I should better spend the time learning some „real“ programming languages.

What do you think?

Answer (score 9):

It's been a long time since I wrote a resume, so my ideas might be dated.  I'm a mechanical engineer.  I write a fair number of reports with lots of citations, tables, figures, etc.  I found and started using LaTeX about 15 years ago because MSWord would make me want to put my hand through the wall on a regular basis.  With LaTeX, I know that if something isn't working, it's my fault and I can find a solution.

I think there is no downside to listing LaTeX as one of your proficiencies.  I would also list MSOffice just to keep them from tossing your resume.

More importantly, **I would include a paragraph on how I love to learn new software and technologies to automate repetitive tasks**, with LaTeX as an example.  If you like LaTeX, it should be easy for you to gain some basic knowledge of a couple programming languages.  Personally, I get a lot of use out of:

- **[GAWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK)** - for manipulating large test data files, and
- **[Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/)** - for creating engineering graphics.  Asymptote syntax is a lot like C++ but with built-in vector graphics functions.